# Arial specified in CSS breaks site in IE9

Tags: css, fonts, internet-explorer-9

I've only seen this issue in IE9 and only on certain PCs. In my CSS I have the following, which sometimes causes a blank page:

font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;

If I change the CSS to this then the page loads, but Arial is not used for the font:

font-family: "Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif";

Comment: Can you show us an example?  If it sometimes works, it sounds like it could be an issue with the page simply not loading properly.

Comment: Your second example is basically telling the browser to render that div with a font called 'Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif'

Comment: What does "breaks site" mean? try to be a little bit more specific

Comment: I cant get the site off of its current enviroment

Comment: By "breaks site" I meant "sometimes causes a blank page"

Answer (score 1):

Try:

font-family: "Arial", "Verdana", "Helvetica", "sans-serif";

Comment: I too was getting a completely blank page in IE9 when I had one or more font names not wrapped in quotes at all.


This breaks it
`font-family: Open Sans, "Arial", "Verdana", "Helvetica", "sans-serif";`


This works:
`font-family: "Open Sans", "Arial", "Verdana", "Helvetica", "sans-serif";`


Way to be IE.